# Thread ending unexpectedly. c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, pthreads, sleep

I'm trying to get a hold on pthreads. I see some people also have unexpected pthread behavior, but none of the questions seemed to be answered.

The following piece of code should create two threads, one which relies on the other. I read that each thread will create variables within their stack (can't be shared between threads) and using a global pointer is a way to have threads share a value. One thread should print it's current iteration, while another thread sleeps for 10 seconds. Ultimately one would expect 10 iterations. Using break points, it seems the script just dies at

```
while (*pointham != "cheese"){
```

It could also be I'm not properly utilizing code blocks debug functionality. Any *pointers* (har har har) would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string hamburger = "null";
string * pointham = &hamburger;

void *wait(void *)
{
    int i {0};
    while (*pointham != "cheese"){
        sleep (1);
        i++;
        cout << "Waiting on that cheese " << i;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *cheese(void *)
{
    cout << "Bout to sleep then get that cheese";
    sleep (10);
    *pointham = "cheese";
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{

   pthread_t threads[2];
   pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, cheese, NULL);
   pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, wait, NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `pointham` variable is useless. Just use `hamburger` directly.

Comment: It was like that originally, I just started throwing stuff at the wall to see if something would stick.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use `pthread`s instead of `std::thread`? The interface is a lot easier (and it's portable, yay!). Don't shoot yourself in the foot: Avoid pointers and pointy libraries.

Comment: I read that thread is not as portable. posix threads are everywhere and well maintained. boost::thread, works well, and is written by the same guy as that wrote thread, but you're introducing a 3rd party library. I also read that dependent on your compiler std::thread implementation is sketch. I'm total noob sauce though so all of that could be incorrect. But considering the fun I was having trying to get regex to work with gcc earlier version, I just want to avoid anything that may have poor implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you start your threads, then exit the process (thereby killing your threads). You have to wait for your threads to exit, preferably with the [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) function.

Comment: On the first function, the while loop should prevent the thread from exiting. *pointham is not equal to "cheese" so it should never even get to the exit, and on the 2nd function a 10 second sleep should prevent the thread from exiting. I also did do an iteration where I didn't exit threads, same result. If I'm missing something though, please elaborate.

Comment: @RyanLewkowicz When you run a program, it's in a separate process, and if the process exits all threads created and not detached will be killed with the process. That the threads themselves loops won't help as all threads are part of the same process. Application exit leads to process exit which leads to thread termination.

Comment: Very cool. Good call man.

I know it's jank, I just add a while loop in my main function and it worked as intended:

       while (*pointham != "cheese"){
          sleep(11);
       }
 
I imagine if I called the second function not as a thread, it would put the main thread to sleep while the child thread ran. The loop may not be necessary at that point. In any case I just wanted to demonstrate functionality to my self. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to join all your threads, you can call pthread_exit() in the *main* thread instead of returning from main().

But note the BUGS section from the manpage:

```
   Currently, there are limitations in the kernel implementation logic for
   wait(2)ing on a stopped thread group with a dead thread  group  leader.
   This  can manifest in problems such as a locked terminal if a stop sig‐
   nal is sent to a foreground  process  whose  thread  group  leader  has
   already called pthread_exit().
```

Comment: Ty for the input, I'd upvote you, but I can't vote yet.

Comment: yeah, I know what that's like

Answer (score 0):

According to this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm):

> If main() finishes before the threads it has created, and exits with pthread_exit(), the other threads will continue to execute. Otherwise, they will be automatically terminated when main() finishes.

So, you shouldn't end the `main` function with the statement `return 0;`. But you should use `pthread_exit(NULL);` instead.

If this doesn't work with you, you may need to learn about joining threads [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm).